# SOAP adapter failure when called in Android device

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

I am working with HTTP (SOAP) adapters in IBM MobileFirst Platform 7. Everything  works fine in the Console, but when I tried to run the app in a real device it is failing and the web service is not getting called.

The Logcat is showing the following:

```
05-05 17:33:11.012: W/PluginManager(13237): THREAD WARNING: exec() call to WLAuthorizationManagerPlugin.getClientInstanceIdHeader blocked the main thread for 173ms. Plugin should use CordovaInterface.getThreadPool().
05-05 17:33:11.032: D/wl.request(13237): WLRequestSender.run in WLRequestSender.java:40 :: Sending request http://192.168.1.43:10080/Adapters/authorization/v1/clients/instance
05-05 17:33:11.072: D/dalvikvm(13237): GC_CONCURRENT freed 4707K, 24% free 19499K/25604K, paused 4ms+3ms, total 60ms
05-05 17:33:21.092: D/wl.certManager(13237): WLCertManager.clearKeystore in WLCertManager.java:258 :: Key store cleared.
05-05 17:33:21.122: D/NONE(13237): Client registration failed with error: {"status":500,"responseHeaders":{},"responseText":"","invocationContext":null}
05-05 17:33:21.132: E/NONE(13237): [/apps/services/api/CallingAdapters/android/query] failure. state: 500, response: undefined
```

What the steps should follow to work with HTTP Adapters on real devices?

Here is my code:

index.htm

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>CallingAdapters</title>
<meta name="viewport"
    content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
<script>
    window.$ = window.jQuery = WLJQ;
</script>
<script>
    function mSuccess(result) {

                var httpStatusCode = result.status;
                if (200 == httpStatusCode) {
                    var invocationResult = result.invocationResult;
                    var isSuccessful = invocationResult.isSuccessful;
                    if (invocationResult.isSuccessful) {
                        var CelsiusToFahrenheitResponse = invocationResult.CelsiusToFahrenheitResponse;
                        var res = CelsiusToFahrenheitResponse.CelsiusToFahrenheitResult;
                        alert("Success::::" + res);
                    } else {
                        alert("Error. isSuccessful=" + isSuccessful);
                    }
                }


    }
</script>
<script>
    function mFailure(result) {
        alert("Failure");
    }
</script>
<script>
    function callFunc() {
        var value = $('#input1').val()
                var invocationData = {
                    adapter : 'SOAPAdapter',
                    procedure : 'temperatureConvertor',
                    parameters : [ value ]
                };

        WL.Client.invokeProcedure(invocationData, {
            onSuccess : mSuccess,
            onFailure : mFailure,
        });
    }
</script>
</head>
<body style="display: none;">
    <!--application UI goes here-->
    Hello MobileFirst By Sravana Lakshmi

    <div>
        <input id="input1" type="number" />
    </div>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" onclick="callFunc()" />
    <script src="js/initOptions.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    <script src="js/messages.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

SOADAdapter.xml

```
<wl:adapter name="SOAPAdapter"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:wl="http://www.ibm.com/mfp/integration"
    xmlns:http="http://www.ibm.com/mfp/integration/http">

    <displayName>SOAPAdapter</displayName>
    <description>SOAPAdapter</description>
    <connectivity>
        <connectionPolicy xsi:type="http:HTTPConnectionPolicyType">
            <protocol>http</protocol>
            <domain>www.w3schools.com</domain>
            <port>80</port>         
            <connectionTimeoutInMilliseconds>30000</connectionTimeoutInMilliseconds>
            <socketTimeoutInMilliseconds>30000</socketTimeoutInMilliseconds>
            <maxConcurrentConnectionsPerNode>50</maxConcurrentConnectionsPerNode>   
        </connectionPolicy>
    </connectivity>

    <procedure name="temperatureConvertor"/>
</wl:adapter>
```

SOAPAdapter-impl.js

function temperatureConvertor(celsiusTemp) {

```
var request = 
    <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
        <soap:Body>
            <CelsiusToFahrenheit xmlns="http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/">
                <Celsius>{celsiusTemp}</Celsius>
            </CelsiusToFahrenheit>
        </soap:Body>
    </soap:Envelope>;

    var input = {
        method: 'post',
        returnedContentType: 'xml',
        path: '/webservices/tempconvert.asmx',
        body: {
            content: request.toString(),
            contentType: 'text/xml; charset=utf-8',
        },
    };

    var result = WL.Server.invokeHttp(input);

    return result.Envelope.Body;
};
```

Comment: Is this WL 6.2 (or above)? Are you using a self signed certificate or one signed by a trusted certificate authority?

Comment: iam working with wlPlatformVersion 7. Sorry! how to check the certificate and what actually is that.@McGee

Comment: I think I need more information about what you are trying to do. I recall having a problem with authenticating with a custom adapter and self signed SSL certificates. Check here for info: https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/admin/c_ssl_config.html

Comment: I am calling a soap(HTTP Adapter) web service in my hybrid app and then I am adding Android mobile  first Environment to run on a device. I've followed this tutorial https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-0/server-side-development/java-adapter/#sample@McGee

Comment: Everything works fine on the Android Virtual Device but you get a 500 when using a real device. Is that correct? Can you get to 192.168.1.43:10080 from the hardware device?

Comment: @sravanalakshmi.sunkara, provide your MFP project so we could debug it.

Comment: @sravanalakshmi.sunkara, also edit the question with your adapter XML and JS, as well as the client-side implementation (sending the request, handling the response).

Comment: Yes getting  500 when using a real device. I could not  able to connect to  192.168.1.43:10080 from the hardware device.@McGee

Comment: @sravanalakshmi.sunkara, waiting for your responses to all of the questions above.

Comment: No the problem is not solved yet. But the problem is all about the server. My device and the system is not connected to same network and  is not able to connect to 192.168.1.43:10080 from the device. This is the answer on which I am working on it http://stackoverflow.com/q/29664406/2260073@IdanAdar

Comment: So did you change the host value for the development server and re-built the app or not?

Comment: But I don't understand what actually the Host value means and why it is necessary to work with Mobile development. @IdanAdar.

Comment: This is the value that is injected into the mobile app. Adapter requests go to the mobilefirst server. Without a correct host URL (of the server), adapter urls will fail.

Comment: Then why it is working on mobile light simulator/web? Why getting problem only with real devices @IdanAdar

Comment: Because devices have internal IP addresses. If providing an incorrect address such as localhost the device will use its own... local address, thus fail. This question is going on too long - provide your project.

Comment: Okay@IdanAdar. thanku for the response. I've understood the concept. Means it is necessary that project should be hosted on our public domain. Then every thing will work fine. Right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77274/discussion-between-sravanalakshmi-sunkara-and-idan-adar).

Answer (score 0):

The answer you reference assumes that you know an ipaddress of the server that can be reached by the device.

The key point here is that your device has different network connectivity from that which your development environment sees. The code running on the device must be able to see the server, that's where the adapter is running.

Try this:

Load up the MFP console in a browser on your desktop. What URL are your using?

Does that URL work in a browser on your device?

If for example it was:

```
 http://localhost:10080/xyz/console
```

or

```
  http://127.0.0.1:10080/xyz/console
```

Then pretty obviously that cannot work on your device. But given that your device is probably on some completely different network then your desktop machine may not be visible to the device. For example:

```
  http://192.168.0.19:10080/xyz/console
```

May well not be reachable. In extreme cases it may not even be possible to get to the server. For example some corporations have a policy that mobile devices may not be connected  to the corporate network, instead they can only be attached to a "guest" network, which deliberately does not give access to the development networks. In such cases we may need to get special networks to be set up for testing. For example, on occasions I set up my own isolated WiFi network that my development machine and my device can use.